# sequelize instanceMethods

Tags: node.js, underscore.js, sequelize.js

I'm trying to configurate my database ,i want the data returned to user doesn't include some sensetive data, so i'm adding an **instanceMethods** named **toPublicJSON** that using a function named **pick** from **underscoreJS** , but when i use this function (**toPublicJSON**) I encounter an error : that **toPublicJSON** is not a **function**

this my database configuration:

```
var bcrypt = require("bcrypt");
var _ = require("underscore");

module.exports = function(sequelize, DataType) {
    return sequelize.define('users', {
        email: {
            type: DataType.STRING,
            allowNull: false,
            unique: true,
            validate: {
                isEmail: true

            }
        },
        salt: {
            type: DataType.STRING
        },
        hassedPassword: {
            type: DataType.STRING
        },
        password: {
            type: DataType.VIRTUAL,
            allowNull: false,
            validate: {
                len: [7, 100]
            },
            set: function(value) {
                var salt = bcrypt.genSaltSync(10);
                var hashed_password = bcrypt.hashSync(value, salt);
                this.setDataValue('password', value);
                this.setDataValue("salt", salt);
                this.setDataValue("hassedPassword", hashed_password);

            }
        }
    }, {
        hooks: {
            beforeValidate: function(user, option) {
                if (typeof user.email == 'string')
                    user.email = user.email.toLowerCase();
            }
        },

        instanceMethods:{
            toPublicJSON: function() {
                var json = this.toJSON();
                return _.pick(json, 'id', 'email', 'createdAt', 'updatedAt');

            }
        }
    });
}
```

my code :

```
app.post('/users',function(req,res){
    var body=_.pick(req.body,"email","password");
    db.users.create(body).then(function(user){
        return res.send(user.toPublicJSON());
    },function(e){
        return res.status(400).json(e);
    })

});
```

and this is the error :

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you are using the latest version of Sequelize they changed slightly how to define instance and class methods.  You need to assign functions to the prototype of the result of `sequelize.define('users');`.  You will need to save the results of `sequelize.define` to a variable, similar to below...

```
const User = sequelize.define('users', {});
User.prototype.toPublicJSON = function() {
  // Your code here
};
return User;
```

If you're on version 3 let me know.

Good luck :)

EDIT: Further reading material http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/models-definition.html#expansion-of-models

EDIT 2: You may want to look into scopes.  They are essentially pre-baked filters you can apply to your data when querying for them. http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/scopes.html

If you did that then you could say

```
sequelize.define('users', {
  // Attributes...
}, {
  scopes: {
    public: {
      attributes: ['id', 'email', 'createdAt', 'updatedAt']
    }
  }
});

db.users.scope('public').findOne({...});
```

Comment: If you define the `toPublicJSON` as a prototype function of your Sequelize table like I did it should work for you.  You would just need to slightly tweak how you define the model to do so.